# How to change Keyframes background color using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Hi i am using css3 to animate loader and i want to make it color independent. My CSS3 code for keyframes is

```css
#floatingCircle{
    position:relative;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    -moz-transform:scale(0.6);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.6);
    -ms-transform:scale(0.6);
    -o-transform:scale(0.6);
    transform:scale(0.6);
}

.f_circle{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:11px;
    width:11px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-animation-name:f_fadeG;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.04s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction:linear;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-animation-name:f_fadeG;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1.04s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction:linear;
    -ms-border-radius:5px;
    -ms-animation-name:f_fadeG;
    -ms-animation-duration:1.04s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -ms-animation-direction:linear;
    -o-border-radius:5px;
    -o-animation-name:f_fadeG;
    -o-animation-duration:1.04s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -o-animation-direction:linear;
    border-radius:5px;
    animation-name:f_fadeG;
    animation-duration:1.04s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-direction:linear;
}
#frotateG_01{
    left:0;
    top:25px;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.39s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.39s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.39s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.39s;
    animation-delay:0.39s;
}

#frotateG_02{
    left:7px;
    top:7px;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.52s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.52s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.52s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.52s;
    animation-delay:0.52s;
}

#frotateG_03{
    left:25px;
    top:0;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.65s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.65s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.65s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.65s;
    animation-delay:0.65s;
}

#frotateG_04{
    right:7px;
    top:7px;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.78s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.78s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.78s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.78s;
    animation-delay:0.78s;
}

#frotateG_05{
    right:0;
    top:25px;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.91s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.91s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.91s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.91s;
    animation-delay:0.91s;
}

#frotateG_06{
    right:7px;
    bottom:7px;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.04s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.04s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.04s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.04s;
    animation-delay:1.04s;
}

#frotateG_07{
    left:25px;
    bottom:0;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.17s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.17s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.17s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.17s;
    animation-delay:1.17s;
}

#frotateG_08{
    left:7px;
    bottom:7px;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.3s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.3s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.3s;
    animation-delay:1.3s;
}

@-moz-keyframes f_fadeG{
    0%{
        background-color:#000000}

    100%{
        background-color:#FFFFFF}

}
```

Kindly help me to change the background color of keyframes 100% part using javascript.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a fairly complex process. First you need to obtain the keyframes object in javascript, then you have to create a new version. Following is an untested version that would work (likely with some changes), but I don't think it would work like you want it to

**NOTE:** The way this is set up currently it only works with webkit, you'd need to add more browser prefixes if you want to serve all browsers

```
// Function to get the keyframe object based on the name
function findKeyframesRule(rule) {
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++j) {
            if (ss[i].cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE && 
                ss[i].cssRules[j].name == rule) { return ss[i].cssRules[j]; }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Function to change the last keyframe of the given animation to the new color
function changeAnimColor(animationName, color) {
    var keyframes = findKeyframesRule(animationName);
    keyframes.deleteRule('100'); 
    keyframes.insertRule("100% { background-color:" + color + "; }");
}

changeAnimColor("f_fadeG", "#FF00FF");
```

I believe you are wanting to change the animation to allow each `frotateG` to have its own color, but this approach would change the color of the background color of the animation which each uses so they'd all be the same. The easiest way to make each have their own animation color would be to not use js but create an individual CSS animation for each object of the type. Then you could use something like the function I provided to change the animation color on click or something using an array and some recursion if you'd like

For more information on this topic, you might look at my article on CSS Tricks about Javascript interaction with CSS Animations and Transitions [**found here**](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/)